# Delete multiple objects from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to delete multiple object inside database? I have 20 tables, 40 views, 40 stored procedures, 20 triggers.

I don't want to delete them one by one. I've been naming all the objects starting with `_`, e.g. `_TableName`, `_ViewName`, `_StoredProcedureName`, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using dynamic SQL and query [catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for your objects (there's one for tables, views, procedures, etc.). You can then build up a list of `drop` statement separated by `;` and execute it.

For example, for dropping tables it will be:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N''

select @sql = @sql + N'drop table ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N'; ' 
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where left(t.name, 1) = '_'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I tried your code from new query windows then execute it.. It doesn't work. My table wasn't drop.

Comment: @Haminteu Sorry, when copying the code I missed the line that actually executes it. Please try now.

Comment: sys.tables.. Its for table, how about view ? Storeprocedure ?

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx. There's a view for views, procedures, triggers, etc.